# Qt3d Slow rendering of thousands of curves

Tags: qt3d

From qt3d, I would like to pick an arbitrary number of face normals drawn at each facet of a mesh.

Once the number of normals (drawn as individual lines each with its own VBO and attached QObjectPicker) exceeds a couple of thousand instances, the rendering speed slows to a crawl.

I feel like there must be a better way to do this that preserves rendering speed. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should describe your question a bit better. How do you pick face normals (this is not supported by Qt3D - you can either pick triangles, points, lines or all three)? Do all the lines belong to the same object? If so, you could use one object picker and set the picking settings to `line picking`.

Comment: Florian, glad you responded. You seem to always answer these Qt3d questions here. I derived a custom QObjectPicker to select curves by using PrimitivePicking. Actually, my problem involves edge curves from importing a CAD model, but I dumbed down my question. If all of my curves belong to the same object (currently they do not), can I modify attributes (color, thickness, etc) of the selected curve(s)? This is why I choose to naively put them into their own VBOs.

Comment: Well, don't expect to much, I'm not entirely an expert ;) Did you try not to add the object pickers? Is there a difference in rendering speed int his case? If you want to modify the attributes of just one curve you could e.g. give it an ID, but I'm not sure if this is best practice.

Comment: I am no expert by far either. I did try not adding the pickers, but the rendering speed was still dog slow. Good idea about assigning an ID attribute within a single QGeometry object containing all the curves. Would an QObjectPicker be able to pick just one of the internal curves? If so, that may be my solution.

Comment: Is it possible to have an indexBuffer of variable "internal entity" size, i.e., some curves having 15 line segments, some having 11 line segments, etc?

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a useful solution to your problem. Are all the lines always within the view of the camera? I'm asking because you could try to attach `QFrustumCulling` to your framegraph, if you already haven't. I'm not sure whether the defaul framegraph of the `Qt3DWindow` has such a node present.

Comment: Do you need this `internal entity size` because you don't want all lines to be connected? The only thing that I can think of is to somehow set the alpha of the segments to `0`, that you don't want to be drawn. But I don't think this is easily achievable.

Comment: This was kind of suggested from the Qt forum: I need to minimize draw calls by putting all my curves into a single VBO and perform picking in an off-screen binary tree. Then update the selected objects by redrawing the single VBO with selected entities having modified attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I need a variable `internal node count size` because CAD curves are disjoint and plus I need to modify their attributes if picked.

Comment: Something that I could work is to render the segments twice, onscreen once and offscreen once. When you render them offscreen, you pass their ID to the vertex shader and encode it in their color (which you have to specify as flat, so that it doesn't get interpolated). This way you can encode 256^3 IDs (due to the three color channels, 256^4 if you take alpha into account). You then retrieve this image using `QRenderCapture` and if the user clicks you retrieve the color from the image and check which segment was hit. I'm not sure how well this works in Qt, though.

Comment: My experiences with offscreen rendering in Qt3D are rather unsatisfactory. I've written an [offscreen renderer](https://github.com/florianblume/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer) though.

Comment: http://xeolabs.com/articles/scenejs-ray-picking-technique

Comment: The more I get to know Qt3d, I more see it is a C++ port of SceneJS and its successor, xeogl.